# Importing separate tabs of Excel spreadsheets into separate tables of MS Access database

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I have a table called `Pathmap` with a column `Path` which is a list of filepaths of files I want to import

I then run the following code to try and import all these files into two tables in my database. One sheet called sts from each file goes into table1, and another sheet from within each file called CP goes into table2.

```
Sub pulloop()
DoCmd.RunSQL "delete * from table1"
DoCmd.RunSQL "delete * from table2"
strSql = "PathMap"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)


With rs
If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
.MoveLast
.MoveFirst
    While (Not .EOF)
    importfile = rs.Fields("Path")
    objAccess.NewCurrentDatabase "Nate"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "TABLE1", importfile, true, STS
   DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "TABLE2", importfile, True, CP
   'Debug.Print rs.Fields("Path")
    .MoveNext
    Wend
    End If
.Close
End With
End Sub
```

Problem is that it debugs, telling me that a field I know is only in the STS sheet of my importfiles, does not exist in destination Table2. It doesn't seem to actually be pulling from the CP sheet of the import file, but the STS one, and I am not sure what is wrong with my syntax here.

Help greatly appreciated. Difficulty with different tabs to different tables via docmd. transferspreadhseet.

Comment: what are the values of the variables `STS` and `CP`

Comment: sts and cp are just the names of the sheets in the import workbooks.

Comment: `STS` and `CP` are variables (they don't have quotes around them) If they're not declared somewhere outside the Sub their values are going to be `Empty` which is probably why you're having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the behavior described

this

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
                          acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                         "TABLE2", _
                          importfile, _
                          true, _
                          CP
```

is doing the same

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
                          acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                         "TABLE2", _
                          importfile, _
                          true, _
                          Empty
```

When you write `CP` without quotes you are creating a variable called `CP` that is of type variant and assigning it the value `Empty`.

When DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet receives a value of `Empty` for the `range` parameter it assumes you want the first spreadsheet. This is why Access is telling you that fields in STS don't exist in table2.

The way to fix this is to give the range value you want

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
                          acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                         "TABLE2", _
                          importfile, _
                          true, _
                          "CP!"
```

I recommend you also add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module so that you don't accidentally make these mistakes later. Of course this does mean you'll need to declare rs and strSql.

Comment: Thanks that makes total sense, however I am now failing on the second file with "Field F8 doesn't exist in destination table 'Table 1'" . there is only 7 columns in the CP tab, and there are dozen or so in the STS tab of import workbooks. It imported the first file fine, and the columns of the 1st and 2nd imnport file are exactly the same. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: @user3049991 There's probably a value of some sort in column `H`. It's probably better to just restrict the range to the columns you care about. e.g. `"CP!A:G"`

Comment: @user3049991  misread your comment. So first I would use "STS!" Second it sounds like their's no header in the "H" column.

Comment: There is no data in the H column and no header, So I dont want it to look at that. I have amended it to be "!CPA:G" but now I get a strange   error saying "Microsoft Office access was unable to append all the data to the table. The contents of x records were deleted and 0 records were lost due to key violations. If data was deleted, the data you pasted or imported doesnt match the field data types or the Field Size Property in the destination table." I click proceed and the data looks fine. What is this? And is it possible to code always for it to answer Yes to this? It pops up for each file!

Comment: Add `DoCmd.SetWarnings False ` before the `TransferSpreadSheet ` and then add `DoCmd.SetWarnings True `  after